# How Do I Convert A Cut Command In Bash Into Grep With Given Code?

Tags: bash, shell, grep, sh, cut

I've written a template engine script that uses cut to extract certain elements from a file, but I want to use grep in place of the cut. Here is the code I have written:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=@  #makes @ a delimiter. 
while read line
do
  dataspace=`echo ${line} | cut -d'=' -f1` 
  value=`echo ${line} | cut -d"=" -f2` 
  printf -v $dataspace "$value" #make the value stored in value into the name of a dataspace.
done < 'template.vars' #read template.vars for standard input.

skipflag=false           #initialize the skipflag to false                       
while read line  #while it is reading standard input one line at a time
```

Just came to the conclusion that the code blocks system here does not support bash.
Anyway, since stackoverflow isn't letting me put Bash into codeblocks, I am not putting the entire script since it would look nasty.  Based on what is currently high-lighted, how would I go about changing the part using the cut command into a line using the grep command?

Comment: Indent the code with 4 spaces at the left. The code seems incomplete

Comment: ... also it's not quite clear from your code what is the input, what you're going to achieve and why you think that `grep` is better than `cut` for your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been noted, you should give more information for a better answer. Going with what you have, I would say that `awk` is a better option than `grep`

```
dataspace=$(awk '$0=$1' FS== <<< "$line")
    value=$(awk '$0=$2' FS== <<< "$line")
```

Comment: thanks, this helped a lot.  Imagine the numbers represent columns, and the equal sign is being ignored (or something along those lines)